# Make object structured cloneable

Tags: javascript, three.js, web-worker

Is there an automatic way to make an arbitrary JavaScript object structured cloneable by removing all methods from the object?

In my specific usecase I'm creating three.js BufferAttribute objects in a web worker and I want to transfer them to the main thread.

My current approach is to create a new object in the web worker that has the 
same members as the original object, just without the methods. This object is transferred to the main thread and in the main thread I create a proper three.js BufferAttribute object again and assign the properties to it.

Comment: `JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(object))`?

Comment: Are you worried about the prototype chain?

Comment: @adiga Since the object contains ArrayBuffers I would like to preserve them and transfer them instead of copying them to the main thread.

Comment: @ScottSauyet No actually there is no prototype chain for three.js BufferAttribute

Comment: Then I think either adiga's comment or T.J. Crowder's answer should do you fine.  If you have more complicated objects, it get's much harder... eventually impossible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not *automatic*, but you can use [`Object.fromEntries`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/fromEntries), [`Object.entries`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries), and [`filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter):

```
const objectWithoutMethods = Object.fromEntries(
    Object.entries(originalObject).filter(([k, v]) => typeof v !== "function")
);
```

`Object.fromEntries` and `Object.entries` are relatively new, but easily polyfilled.